# Why textbox doesn't print the text, but I got string ?

Tags: c#, interface, windows-forms-designer

I am using Windows Form;

I want to set TextBox `tbCommandName1.Text` which is on my Form;

I got the value from `GetInfo()` and how can I send string from `Second.GetInfo()` to my main Form like to class `Favorit` ?

I don't want to create an instance of `Form`; Because it makes to Initialize all my components again.
I bet I have to use get/set. 
Give me please, a few hints;
THanks a lot to you, my guru!

```
 namespace ParserFavorit
    {
        public partial class Favorit : Form, IForm
        {
            public Favorit()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

        public string CommandName1
        {
            get { return tbCommandName1.Text; }
            set { tbCommandName1.Text = value; }
        }

        private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = tbGetID.Text;
            Second.StartBrowser(Second.GetDriver(), ID);            
        }


    }
    public class Second : Form
    {
        private static ChromeDriver driver = null;
        public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }

        public static void StartBrowser(ChromeDriver driver, string IDevent)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("myURL" + IDevent);
            GetInfo();
        }

        public static void GetInfo()   
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).Text;
            string CommandName2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[2]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");   
        }  
    }

    interface IForm
    {
        string CommandName1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put that code in a form, put it in a class that is designed for that responsibility.

Comment: Unable to get what you exactly want to say.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for me about using interface with get set ?

Comment: You don't want or need an instance but a reference to the form. many post on that..

Comment: Dear friend! I am trying to do that for a few days. Can you please, help me a bit?

Comment: I even try to use `Favorit favorit = new Favorit(); favorit.PrintName(CommandName1);` and then in my class Favorite `public void PrintName(string Command1Name)
        {
            tbCommandName1.Text = Command1Name;` it doesnt help me also. How so?

Comment: Method `PrintName` got the value with type string. But my Form doesn't show it at textbox. How so?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that I have a TextBox with name tbCommandName1; 
My form doesn't show the value which I got from website, but method `PrintName` got it. 
How so?

namespace ParserFavorit
{
    public partial class Favorit : Form
    {
        public Favorit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = tbGetID.Text;
        Second.StartBrowser(Second.GetDriver(), ID);
    }

    public void PrintName(string Command1Name)
    {
        string Name = Command1Name;
        tbCommandName1.Text = Name;
    }
}
public class Second
{
    private static ChromeDriver driver = null;
    public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
    {
        if (driver == null)
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static void StartBrowser(ChromeDriver driver, string ID)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://m.favorit.com.ua/uk/live/events/" + ID);
        GetInfo();    
    }



    public static void GetInfo()   
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        string CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).Text;
        Favorit favorit = new Favorit();
        favorit.PrintName(CommandName1);
    }
}
```

}